# Android, is there a way to display two browsers (or better to say two WebViews) at the same time?

Tags: android, android-activity, webview

The question is preatty simple. **Is there a way to display two separate web browsers\webViews (that point to the two diffrent web pages) at the same time.** I want to build an app that show Google search and Bing search at the same page of an app.

I'm asking this becose i was told by my frend (he is an Androind developer) that there is NO WAY to do it?

Is it true? or there is some way to do it?

### **PS: NO IFRAMES PLZ!! I know i can do iframe, but in my case i want it to be two seaparete browsers.**

**UPDATE**

I just want to know is it possible or not. I don't ask you to do my "homework"

Comment: i just wan't to be shure that this is theoreticly is possible. As far as i know documentation says that - "To provide a WebView in your own Activity, include a in your layout, or set the entire Activity window as a WebView during onCreate()". So it's basicly says that i can use only one WebView per one activity, but i nead two.

Comment: about "Why not just try it".. to say the truth... i'm not an android developer, i just want to "port" my Windows Phone application to Android, i just don't want to spend my time if this simply dosn't possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a layout with two `WebView`s beneath eachother, and assign them different id's.
Not tested it, but should be logical.

Also, why does your friend think it's impossible?

**edit**

As per your comment: only if you do it the second way you can have maximum one `WebView` per Activity, I can't find a reason why it should restrict when adding them in a layout.

Comment: I sad it's earlier, but i'm goint to repeat my self. As far as i know documentation says this "To provide a WebView in your own Activity, include a in your layout, or set the entire Activity window as a WebView during onCreate()", so it basicly means that i can have one WebView per Activity, but i nead two

Comment: well, i'm not an Android expret, but he told me that i can have only ONE web view per Activity and it must be full screen. I just really don't know is it true or not. But i didn't find any information about that in the internet and in documentation... so.. that's why i'm asking for your help :)

Comment: I just checked that, and it's working. I have no idea WHY i was told that this would not wokr o_O